# Maximum the distance between multiple vectors for a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors, linear-programming

If you have multiple matrices $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, \dots A_n$

All these matrices are going to be multiply by a vector $x$

$$A_ix$$

The product of $A_ix$ can we call $b_i$

$$b_i = A_ix$$

The goal of this question is:

I know $A_i, i = 1, \dots, n$ and I want to find $x$. To determine $x$, the distance between each $b_i$ (L2-norm) must be maximized. No $b_i$ can be equal.

How can I maximum the distance between multiple vectors for a linear system? What method should I use?

$$A_1x \neq A_2x \neq A_3x \neq A_4x \neq \dots A_ix$$

**Example:**

Assume that you have these following matrices.

```
>> A = [5 2 3 5; 2 4 6 6; 2 4 5 6; 3 1 0 10]
A =

    5    2    3    5
    2    4    6    6
    2    4    5    6
    3    1    0   10

>> B = [4 2 5 6; 2 4 6 1; 79  2 52 2; 43 5 67 2]
B =

    4    2    5    6
    2    4    6    1
   79    2   52    2
   43    5   67    2

>>
```

You want to make sure that

$$Ax \neq Bx$$

So how close can $Ax$ and $Bx$ be? Well, that's the goal of the selecting $x$. Select $x$ so $Ax$ and $Bx$ is far away for each other as possible. For exampel, selecting $x = 0$ is not the best idea.

Comment: Something is not right with your question. If you find any $x$ where the $b_i$ are not equal then you can scale $x$ by $c$ and then the distances between each $b_i$ would be $c$ times larger. You can make the distance infinitely large.

Comment: When you say, "the distance between each $b_i$ must be maximised", what do you mean? The distance between each $b_i$ and what? It sounds like you want to maximise the distances between each $b_i$ and $b_j$ where $i \neq j$, but then how are you proposing to maximise several variables at once?

Comment: To maximize the distance between multiple vectors in a linear system, you can use the method of alternating projections.

Comment: @TheoBendit Exactly. I want to maximum the distance between $b_i$ and $b_j$ where $i \neq j$

Comment: @euraad Sure, but there are still issues remaining. As AsAnExerciseProve points out, there can never be a maximum under the given conditions. Is there some kind of upper bound on $x$? If you fix that, then there's my question about how you're going to optimise multiple variables at once. If you increase the distance between $b_1$ and $b_2$, then it may decrease the distance between $b_2$ and $b_3$. How do we know which situation is optimal? You can't just maximise all $\binom{n}{2}$ distances at once!

Comment: @TheoBendit Good question. Never thougth about that. I don't have any limits for $x$. They can be anything. The question below explains that I can use nullspace to solve for $x$. I think that might be a solution. Assume that we have $A_1$ and $A_2$ and we ar going to make sure that $b_1 \neq b_2$. If for example $b _1= [5; 7]$, then $b_2$ can be like $b_2 = [-5; -7]$. That's a good distance. Totaly reversed. But in this case we don't know $b_i$ at all. This must be a least square problem?

Comment: The problem isn't really well-defined enough to classify! Sam treated the problem as a least squares problem, and used it to **minimise** the distances (well, the sum of their squares), rather than maximise them. To be clear, Sam has found all the $x$ so that $b_1 = b_2 = \ldots = b_n$, as this is the minimum value of their objective function (achieved at $x = 0$, and sometimes elsewhere). That is, Sam's solutions are not even feasible solutions to your original problem! Without limits on $x$, or something similar, there simply is no possible way to proceed with the problem.

Comment: @TheoBendit I'm the one that asking the question. I don't know about the problem, except the goal I want to achieve. Sam says that nullspace can be used, perhaps. I don't know. It seems so. Feel free to create your own solution to this problem, as long $b_i$ is not equal to each other.

Comment: @TheoBendit I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to extremize the sum of the distances between each pair of output vectors $b_i,b_j$, you're really looking to extremize the function:
$$f(x)=\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \|b_i-b_j\|^2 =\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \|(A_i-A_j)x\|^2 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x^T(A_i-A_j)^T(A_i-A_j)x$$
This would be extreme when it's gradient disappears so
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} 2 \left(A_{i}^{T} - A_{j}^{T}\right) \left(A_{i} - A_{j}\right) v = 0$$
This simplifies to
$$\left[\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \left(A_{i}^{T} - A_{j}^{T}\right) \left(A_{i} - A_{j}\right) \right]v = 0$$
That means the vectors you're looking for are the vectors that lie in the null space of
$$\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \left(A_{i}^{T} - A_{j}^{T}\right) \left(A_{i} - A_{j}\right)$$
Just a note at the end, since $f=x^T\left[\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(A_i-A_j)^T(A_i-A_j)\right]x = x^T A x$ where $A$ is symmetric, we can see that $f$ is a quadratic form over $x$. Moreover since $f$ is the sum of distances, we know that the quadratic form is positive definite, therefore this actually corresponds to a minimum, since as the comments suggest, this problem cannot have a maximum.

Comment: Great. Can you show a practical example as well?